# Calculating Cosine Similarity with Large 2d Vector Py

Tags: python, numpy, cosine-similarity

Trying to calculate cosine similarity of a pandas dataframe column. No problems with calculating with small dataset (e.g., 100 samples). Errors occur when dataset increases size to 190k + rows. Is there an alternative way to calculate this?

No error message comes up, but my kernel keeps dying.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

sentence_embeddings=np.array(df['summary_tokens'].tolist(), dtype='float32')

similarity = cosine_similarity(sentence_embeddings)
```

[Sentence Embeddings Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB1Ew.png)

Comment: You are running out of memory. That's why the kernel dies. There is little you can do about it, sadly.

Comment: You can use scipy sparse matrices

Comment: Tried using scipy sparse matrices and received ```RuntimeError: nnz of the result is too large```

Comment: Solution was found after calculating similarity on smaller np arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found after calculating similarity on smaller np arrays!